# paginate data from Firestore on Button Click

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to paginate data from friestore when 'View More' button is clicked. But struggling to get it working...

Code is what I'm working with. It should look like 3 rows then with every click, 3 more 3 and so on

```
const theWorkout = document.getElementById("activity");

const first = query(collection(db, "uuid", uid, "activity", "history", "past-workouts"));

const getNextActivity = async () => {
    var load = query(first, orderBy("order", "desc"), limit(3));

    const moreLoaded = await getDocs(load);

    const latestDoc = data.docs[data.docs.length - 1]

    data.forEach((doc) => {
        const docId = doc.id;
        const Name = "Session: " + doc.data().name;
        const dates = "Date: " + doc.data().date;

        theWorkout.innerHTML += `
            <a href="activity/history.html?id=${docId}"> 
                    <div class="workout-row">
                        <div class="workout-title">${Name}</div>
                        <div class="workout-date">${dates}</div>
                    </div>
                </a>
            `
            console.log("first: ", doc.data());
    });

    var next = query(first, orderBy("order", "desc"), startAfter(latestDoc), limit(1));

    const data_next = await getDoc(next);

    data_next.forEach((doc) => {
        const docId = doc.id;
        const Name = "Session: " + doc.data().name;
        const dates = "Date: " + doc.data().date;

        theWorkout.innerHTML += `
            <a href="activity/history.html?id=${docId}"> 
                    <div class="workout-row">
                        <div class="workout-title">${Name}</div>
                        <div class="workout-date">${dates}</div>
                    </div>
                </a>
            `
            console.log("more: ", doc.data());

    })

    document.getElementById("more").addEventListener("click", function () {
        getNextActivity()
    });
}
```

Comment: "But struggling to get it working..." is hard to help with. What happens when you run this code? Are there any error messages? If not, I recommend locally debugging the code and telling us the result. If you set a breakpoint on each line of the code you shared, run the code in a debugger, and then check the value of each variable on each line, which is the **first** line that doesn't do what you expect it to do?

Comment: E.g. this line looks suspicious `const latestDoc = data.docs[data.docs.length - 1]` as you set `moreLoaded` in the line before and not `data`. But it's hard to say anything conclusive with more debug info.